# Difference of definite integrals inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Could you help me how prove that for any $\mathcal{C}^1$ function we have:

$$\left|\int_{a} ^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f(x) d x - \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}} ^bf(x)dx\right| \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4} \cdot \max _{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)|.$$

Comment: You were missing an integrand, so I edited. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. Could you help me with that?

Comment: You already got an excellent hint. Note that the inequality is optimal, as $f(x)=x$ achieves the equality.

Comment: A small comment: if you replace $\max$ with $\sup$ in the inequality, then both the statment and the answer below are still valid when $f$ is only differentiable, i.e. the continuity of $f'$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Using mean value theorem for $$
\left|\int_{a} ^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f(x) d x - \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}} ^bf(x)dx\right|
=\left|\int_{a} ^{\frac{a+b}{2}}\big[f(x)-f(x+\frac{b-a}{2})\big] d x \right|.
$$

Comment: Could you explain to me why this equality holds?

Comment: @Hagrid $\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^b f(x)dx
=\int_{a} ^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f(x+\frac{b-a}{2})d x$

Comment: I see that. Why do we need floor function?

Comment: @Hagrid I do not know why it becomes floor, I imputed simply square brackets.

Comment: Aha. Thank you. Is it equal to $|F(\frac{a+b}{2})-F(a) - F(\frac{a+b}{2} - \frac{b-a}{2})+F(a + \frac{b-a}{2})|$?, where $F'(x) = f(x)$

Comment: From the mean value theorem we have that there exists $x \in (a, \frac{a+b}{2})$ such that $\left|\int_{a} ^{\frac{a+b}{2}}\big[f(x)-f(x+\frac{b-a}{2})\big] d x \right| = |(f(x) - f(x +\frac{b-a}{2}))(\frac{b-a}{2})|$

Comment: @Hagrid Applying further the mean value theorem for differential.

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: $f(x)-f(y)=f'(\xi)(x-y)$ for $\xi \in [x, y]$

Comment: That's not what I meant. Should I apply this to F, from my comment above?